# How to ensure Meteor publication is reactive to arguments

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, publish-subscribe

Why doesn't the `users` publication publish new data when its `entities` argument changes?

Client code

```
const subReady = useTracker(() => {
  return Meteor.subscribe('users', selectedEntities).ready();
}, [selectedEntities]);
```

Server code

```
Meteor.publish('users', function (entities) {
  check(entities, Match.Maybe(Array));
  const entityUsers = Entities.find(
    {groupName: {$in: entities}},
    {fields: {userIds: 1}},
  )
    .fetch()
    .map(a => a.userIds);
  const userIds = [].concat(...entityUsers);
  console.log(`userIds:`, userIds);
  return Users.find(
    {_id: {$in: userIds}},
    {
      fields: {username: 1, profile: 1, logins: 1, isSNR: 1},
    },
  );
});
```

I expected that since the client is subscribing inside a `useTracker`, when the dependency changes that the client would re-subscribe. Using the Meteor dev tools I'm seeing re-subs as expected, but the publication is only running during the initial sub.

Comment: why is the publication called `users` but you subscribe to `userManager`?

Comment: The pub/sub is called `userManager` in our codebase. I renamed to `users` to simplify the code for this post. I corrected my mistake so thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, publication will rerun when client re-subscibe, but Meteor won't rerun publication if parameter value is the same as the one in previous call. You can add more logs to useTracker callback to check if it's rerun with different parameter value.

Comment: I can see that whenever `entities` changes that the client resubscribes, but my log inside the publication only runs once.

Comment: it's hard to tell you the exact reason now. Could you update your question to provide your client code? Then I can check how it work and strive to figure out the issue

Comment: What additional client code do you need? I posted the client sub above.

Comment: how do you init and handle selectedEntities in your code ?